# Regular expression to select strings with a character appearing on odd occurences

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to create a regex that will select words where the quote character appears on odd occurences. And I'm stuck...

Let's say I have these 4 strings :

- hello'
- pl'pl'op
- 'heger
- qwe'rty

I should get this list in return :

- hello'
- 'heger
- qwe'rty

I'm running around in circles and I don't even know if it is possible to do that in a regex. I'm not so good in regex.

Should I just loop on each characters of all the strings, count the amount of quotes and do a modulo operation to check if the number is odd?

Comment: I think this is your best bet: "loop on each characters of all the strings..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/AljsLk/1)

```
^(?!(?:\w*'\w*'\w*)+$)[\w']+$
```

As per the comments below my question, an improvement can be made by changing the non-capture group to an atomic group as the following pattern demonstrates. This optimization is thanks to [@Thefourthbird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird):

```
^(?!(?>\w*'\w*'\w*)+$)[\w']+$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
hello'
pl'pl'op
'heger
qwe'rty

q'
q'q'
q'q'q'
q'q'q'q'
q'q'q'q'q'
q'q'q'q'q'q'
q'q'q'q'q'q'q'
q'q'q'q'q'q'q'q'
q'q'q'q'q'q'q'q'q'
```

#### Output

Only matches are shown below

```
hello'
'heger
qwe'rty

q'
q'q'q'
q'q'q'q'q'
q'q'q'q'q'q'q'
q'q'q'q'q'q'q'q'q'
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!(?:\w*'\w*'\w*)+$)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match

  - `(?:\w*'\w*'\w*)+` Match any combination of apostrophes and word characters where the apostrophe character appears exactly twice, one or more times (this means 2,4,6,8,10,... times)
  - `$` Assert position at the end of the line
- `[\w']+` Match one or more word characters or apostrophes `'`
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Very nice solution! Question, would it help to create an atomic group `(?>\w*'\w*'\w*)` as an optimization?

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks! I've added the atomic group regex version with proper credits given to you.

Comment: Wow! Very nice solution like @Thefourthbird said. Thanks a lot for the explanations too !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression. Just check if `countMatches` return an odd or not

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String check = "pl'pl'op";

        System.out.println("Ocurrences: " + StringUtils.countMatches(check, "'"));

    }
}
```

Output: `Ocurrences: 2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([^']*'[^']*'[^'])*[^']*'[^']*
```

The idea is to capture in the group an even (possibly 0) number of quotes, and the text between them, and then one more quote.